# 2 enums with same members

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

```
class Class1 < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum enum1: [:val1, :val11, :val111]
  enum enum2: [:val22, :val22, :val222, :heavy]
  enum enum3: [:val1, :val11, val333] 

end
```

This throws an error

```
You tried to define an enum named "val1" on the model "Class1", but this will generate a instance method "val1?", which is already defined by another enum.
```

How can I fix that without having to rename `val1`?  Because I need to display it in a view as it is for `enum1` and `enum3`

Comment: it is wrong to define same values within few `enum`s within one class. It will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Current edge rails offers `enum_prefix` and `enum_suffix` options to deal with unwanted enum conflicts.

Relevant Issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17511